# error: expected class-name before '{' token ERROR

Tags: c++

I have this annoying error in my program.

"Vehicle" is the Base class.
"Bicycle" extends this class.

```
#ifndef BICYCLE_H
#define BICYCLE_H

#include "Vehicle.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Template class which is derived from Vehicle
template<typename T>
class Bicycle: public Vehicle
{
public:
    Bicycle();
    Bicycle(int, int, string, int); 
    ~Bicycle();

    //Redefined functions inherited from Vehicle
    void move(int, int); // move to the requested x, y location divided by 2
    void set_capacity(int); // set the capacity value; can't be larger than 2

};
```

Above is the Bicycle.h file (I do not have .cpp file for this class)

```
#ifndef VEHICLE_H
#define VEHICLE_H

#include "PassengerException.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


//ADD LINE HERE TO MAKE IT A TEMPLATE CLASS
template<typename T>
class Vehicle
{
public:
    Vehicle(); //default contstructor
    Vehicle(int, int, string, int); // set the x, y, name, and capacity
    virtual ~Vehicle(); //destructor; should this be virtual or not???


    //Inheritance - question #1; create these functions here and in Bicycle     class
    string get_name(); // get the name of the vehicle
    void set_name(string); //set the name of the vehicle
    void print(); // std print function (GIVEN TO YOU)

    //Polymorphism - question #2
    virtual void move(int, int); // move to the requested x, y location
    virtual void set_capacity(int); // set the capacity value

    //Operator overloading - question #3
    Vehicle<T> operator+(Vehicle<T> &secondVehicle) const;

    //Exceptions - question #4
    T get_passenger(int) throw(PassengerException); // get the passenger at the specified index
    void add_passenger(T) throw(PassengerException); // add passenger and the current passenger index
    void remove_passenger() throw(PassengerException); // remove a passenger using current passenger index


protected:
    int x_pos;
    int y_pos;
    string name;
    int capacity;
    T *passengers;
    int current_passenger;
};
```

Above is the Vehicle.h file. I do not have .cpp for this either.

Also, what do the ifndef define endif mean? Do I have to use those? Are they required?

And, do their names have to be formatted like that?

Comment: The ifndef endif are to only declare your class once. You're asking (#ifndef) if the class is not defined and if it isn't you define it. It's standard stuff to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Bicycle: public Vehicle
```

Vehicle is a template, so you need this:

```
class Bicycle: public Vehicle<T>
```

The #ifndef and #define and #endif are called header guards and are used to prevent your header file from being included more than once, causing things (classes) to be declared more than once.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thank solved my problem. So one more thing, what are the rules to format those guards? sometimes I see _ in front of the string, and there is no "." like those in xxx.h, or xxx.cpp, but instead _.

Comment: Don't start with an underscore, use a unique name, and keep it consistent. #defines should be all caps as well. I prefer for a file named say `Vehicle.h` to name it `VEHICLE_H` as it is in your post.

Answer (score 0):

The ifndef define and endif are necessary for the actual base files, i.e. the c++ files themselves. Yes they are required, if you plan to use those functions and variables accordingly. Yes, their names have to be formatted that way, that's the way directives or in some cases flags must be formatted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `#endif` at the end of your header files. These are so called define guards to prevent multiple inclusion of header files. See more at [Include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).